# printing array values into a single cell through while loop in fpdf

Tags: php, fpdf

```
$pendReasonNA="select cmpID from onlinecmp where year(cmpDate)='2014'
and  rectstatus=0   
and rectremarks='Not Available in store' 
order by cmpID asc";

$query3=mysql_query($pendReasonNA);
$num_rows=mysql_num_rows($query3);


while($result=mysql_fetch_array($query3))
{
$pdf->Cell(55, 6, $result[0], 1, 0, 'L', 1);
}
```

In the above code what i am getting is value of $result in multiple cells one beside the other.
i would like to print all the values in array $result with a comma separating each array value in a single cell(above cell) in fpdf.
How do i achieve this in fpdf?Plz help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
while($result=mysql_fetch_array($query3))
{
   $queryResult = $queryResult . ', ' .$result[0];
}
$pdf->Cell(55, 6, $queryResult, 1, 0, 'L', 1);
```

The above is adding each result to $queryResult and adding a comma after it, then when all the results are printed it will print the $queryResult to the cell.

Also you should avoid using mysql_* as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12860046/3204827) answer:

> The MySQL extension is:
>
> - Not under active development
> - **Officially [deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation)** (as of PHP 5.5. It's likely to be removed in the next major release.)
> - Lacks an OO interface
> - Doesn't support:
>
>   - Non-blocking, asynchronous queries
>   - **[Prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) or parameterized queries**
>   - Stored procedures
>   - Multiple Statements
>   - Transactions
>   - All of the functionality in MySQL 5.1
>
> Since it is deprecated, using it makes your code less future proof.
>
> Lack of support for prepared statements is particularly important as
>   they provide a clearer, less error prone method of escaping and
>   quoting external data than manually escaping it with a separate
>   function call.
>
> See [**the comparison of SQL extensions**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).